# Deprecated (and no longer available) SDK comments and questions

Tags: discussion, support

If I have provided comments to questions in reference to an SDK that is no longer available, is there an appropriate action to take?

1. Should I delete the comment since it's no longer relevant as the SDK isn't available.
2. Keep the comment even though no one can actually download the SDK in case it's relevant to a migration that should have already happened?
3. Do a late edit of the comment to indicate that it's no longer a viable solution?

Comment: Is the SDK's latest version still available somewhere?

Comment: I'd leave 'em. Nothing ever really goes away.  Smurf, C++ still sees a couple Turbo C++ questions a week, and that hoary ol' beast's been off the market since before the Internet earned its capital I.

Comment: Comments aren't editable after 5 minutes so that's not an option. If the comment would still be useful to someone using the old SDK, you could convert it to an answer.

Comment: An example of such a comment might help contextualize the discussion.

Comment: [Some context](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra) for the Turbo C++ phenomenon. Joshua Fluke on YouTube has also documented it, but I don't currently have a direct reference. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxcFhczzSo) [are](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azkgIOA3y88) [some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INjbQ98bjs8) [leads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6ddSzI_3FI) [for](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifKAlffV8Cs) [it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4K8ULD0md9s).

Comment: No, the SDK has been removed completely.

Comment: What does "has been removed completely" mean in this context, and how is it relevant? A vendor may not exist anymore or no longer provide a download, however such things do not mean there are no copies of said SDK in existence or being distributed anymore. Come to think of it, what do you actually mean with "SDK"?